# Setting baseUrl in npm script doesn't change it (Cypress)

Tags: node.js, npm, cypress, package.json, cypress-configuration

I want to be able to run my Cypress scripts on any URL by modifying the value of `baseUrl` but the command doesn't change it.

```
"cypress open --env version=development --config baseUrl=https://google.com"
```

I have tried env variable too but that also doesn't work:

```
"cypress:open:dev": "cypress open --env version=development,baseUrl=https://google.com"
```

Config file:

```
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const version = config.env.version || 'development'
      const configFile = await import(path.join(
        config.projectRoot,
        'cypress/config',
        `${version}.json`
      ));
      const credentialsFile = await import(path.join(
        config.projectRoot,
        'cypress/config',
        'credentials.json'
      ));
      config = {
        ...config,                    // take config defined in this file
        ...configFile                 // merge/override from the external file
      }
      config.env = {
        ...config.env,                // 2nd level merge
        ...credentialsFile[version]   // from git-ignored file 
      }
      config.baseUrl = configFile.baseUrl
      return config
    },
    reporter: 'mochawesome'
  },
});
```

development.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "baseUrl": "https://test.com",
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the solution that provides what I was looking for:

The command, URL is optional, if not provided it uses the hard-coded value in `development.json`:

```
"cypress:open:dev": "CYPRESS_BASE_URL=$URL cypress open --env version=development"
```

The only line I needed to change in my config was the following:

```
config.baseUrl = config.baseUrl || configFile.env.baseUrl
```

All my tests were using the following:

```
 cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl'))
```

So I needed to change to:

```
 cy.visit('')
```

With this solution, I can run the script without any argument and it will use default `baseUrl`, or I can run `URL="https://google.com/ npm run cypress:open:dev` and the `baseUrl` will change

Comment: This looks an awful lot like the answer @Amirhossein gave.

Comment: Read my reply to that answer and read my answer again. I don't get karma for marking my comment as an answer...

Answer (score 6):

You are overriding the `config.env` settings, and must merge them back into the config.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      ...
      config = {
        ...config,                    // take config defined in this file
        ...configFile,                // merge/override from the external file
        env: {...config.env}          // don't merge env
      }
      ...
      return config
    },
    reporter: 'mochawesome',
    // baseUrl: 'http://example.com',     // cannot use this with above merge!!
  },
})
```

Although, if you do it this way you cannot set `baseUrl` directly as it will take precedence over `development.json`.

Question is, why `env.baseUrl` in `development.json`? Why not follow standard convention and use

**development.json:**

```js
{
  "baseUrl": "https://test.com",
}
```

Comment: The same problem as the other answer, if I omit baseUrl from ```package.json``` script it doesn't pick up the hard-coded value. No issue with development.json, I am able to use ```Cypress.env("baseUrl")```  in tests.

Answer (score 3):

The config gets merged from multiple sources. It would seem that the code in `setupNodeEvents()` is the final setting, i.e it runs after command line overrides have been applied.

Therefore `config.baseUrl = configFile.baseUrl` is causing the problem.

I would change it to

```js
config.baseUrl = config.baseUrl || configFile.baseUrl
```

Since you don't set baseUrl via a hard-coded property in the config,

e.g

```js
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: "some-hard-coded-url",
```

it would be `undefined` when there was no command line override, but have a value if there was a command line override.

So using the OR operator as above, it will only assign `configFile.baseUrl` if there is not a value already.

---

#### Saving .env from the command line

Since you're using `--env` to pass the override, this section merging `config` and `configFile` replaces the `config.env` section entirely, assuming your `development.json` has the structure given in the question.

```js
config = {
  ...config,      // env from command-line overrides are on .env property 
  ...configFile   // env from external file replaces that property entirely
}
```

so anything that follows has no effect.

Instead, save the initial `config.env` and use it later when merging in the credentialsFile.

Now the OR condition (`||`) works as expected,

```js
const env = {...config.env}
config = {...config,...configFile}
config.env = {...env,...credentialsFile[version]}

config.baseUrl = config.env.baseUrl || configFile.env.baseUrl
```

---

#### My results

When I run that, I get `baseUrl: 'https://google.com'` with

```js
"cypress:open:dev": "cypress open --env version=development,baseUrl=https://google.com"
```

and I get `baseUrl: 'https://test.com'` when running

```js
"cypress:open": "cypress open"
```

---

#### configFile has env in the path

Note your `development.json` has `env` in the path before `baseUrl`, so change `configFile.baseUrl` to `configFile.env.baseUrl`.

Comment: I thought the issue might be there and tried before with no luck, your solution doesn't work either, baseUrl remains unchanged.

Comment: Ah, the problem is in `config = { ...config, ...configFile }` - it's overriding the command line env. I assumed you had `--config baseUrl=...` on the command line, but you have `--env baseUrl=...`.

Comment: No, I have tried both command line options and neither worked.

Comment: That's a shame, you could have a typo somewhere - I can make it work.

Comment: I had no problem with the OR condition, but there were a number of issues in the original code.

Comment: That works if I use --env, yes. But I don't get the default baseUrl because my package json uses ```"cypress:open:dev": "cypress open --env version=development```.

Comment: That's different to what you show in the the question, there you also add `baseUrl` to the `--env` list (which is a bit weird since it's not really an env setting). Anyway, that's what was asked and that's what I based the answer on.

Comment: The question title even says ***Setting baseUrl in npm script***

Comment: I simply showed that the ```--env``` command doesn't work also, ```--config``` is the first in question and preference so not sure why so hung up on it. And it's not what I want as I already said, I'll figure it out myself since this is half-baked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in order to set baseUrl:

```
"cypress:open:dev": "CYPRESS_BASE_URL=https://google.com cypress open --env version=development"
```

Comment: Tried that command before too but no luck still.